# What mean "one God"?

Tags: trinity

Thou believest that God is one...
James 2:19 ASV

The Bible teaches us that there is one God. The Doctrine of the Trinity says there is only one being in three persons. What does "one being" mean? Does it refer to the fact that there is only one infinite body in which there are three persons (such as a human being possessed by two demons, that is, a body in which there are 3 persons: 2 demons and man)? Or does it mean that there are 3 bodies that are not really 3, but there is one, and each body is possessed by one person? But how can 3 infinite bodies be ~1.80 meters tall? This is not infinite at all. Or does it mean that there are 3 persons, all of them having the same characteristics, as all humans possess humanity, and therefore there is only one humanity in many people? Or mean something else?
 I want to know what "one being" refers to.

Comment: Welcome to Hermeneutics.SE. Even with this edit, it seems to me your question falls more within systematic theology than in biblical hermeneutics. It may fit better on [christianity.se], but be sure to read their [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to understand what kind of questions they accept. (I do not know that community, but I believe they expect you to ask how a particular denomination tackles this question.)

Answer (score 1):

(I think you should start by familiarizing yourself with echâd and conversely with yachid. And why only echâd is used in reference to the trinity, especially in the Shema Isra’el.)

The concept of the trinity is an ancient Hebrew concept that began to be surpressed when the Pharisees realized Christians were embracing Jesus as the one they referred to as the second power.

So far in my research if I were to distill some things concerning the “form”... Jesus prior to Creation was different to Jesus after Creation and different after incarnation and different after going to the Father.

> “Now, Father, glorify me alongside yourself. Give me the same glory I had with you before the world existed.”
>   ‭‭Yochanan (Jhn)‬ ‭17:5‬ ‭CJB‬‬

That there makes a distinction between prior to creation, incarnation and evidently since he didn’t incarnate after Creation that is a third “form”. Then He got a glorified body

Without going into the theology of predestination from a Christian (non Calvinist) viewpoint, Christians also will be given a body like His

> “because those whom he knew in advance, he also determined in advance would be conformed to the pattern of his Son, so that he might be the firstborn among many brothers;”
>   ‭‭Romans (Rom)‬ ‭8:29‬ ‭CJB‬‬

Christians will get the glorified body the Son has.

So in a sense to answer your question the Father is echâd with the Son and the Spirit of Christ. The Father and the Spirit are spirit. Jesus has a glorified body.

So your question deals mainly with Jesus. In His precreation  state it’s possible He was spirit but I don’t know I can prove it per se just yet. Then He took the form of the sons of Elohim or the elohim, that were spirit but could take human form, however they were not Other like Elohim. Then He incarnated and kenosis, emptied himself and took on human form, about which He seemed to have been excited about because His favorite expression about Himself was Son of Man. And lastly He ascended after the garden incident with Mary (or at some other time) and received a glorified body.

In all echâd. United in purpose, pulling from the same source, moving in the same direction, with perfect agreement and unison. Like a husband and wife that love each other are echâd, the trinity infinitely on a higher level echâd.

My question is did Jesus in fact retain Omniscience, omnipotence and omnipresence whilst incarnate and in fact after Creation when He was like the elohim. But so far I’m still researching.

And to your question how can three infinite beings take residence in one body, a spirit is immaterial, we know that a legion took residence in one man. So three infinite beings taking residence in a multitude of Christians speaks to the properties of the Spirit more than the limited properties of a material unglorfied body.

Comment: You have mastered the practice of eisegesis. The Bible does not state in one verse that, “So in a sense to answer your question the Father is echâd with the Son and the Spirit of Christ” (your quote). With assumptions the Bible teaches any heresy as you demonstrate. The word “God” is found thousands of times in the Bible. Never is the one God Identified as triune.

Comment: Please read below answers to ethos  and address the passages I have related and when you can answer how it’s not speaking of more than one in context I’ll engage further. Until then I’ll take your comment as out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Texts from The NWT:-

> Malachi 2:10   “Do we not all have one father? Was it not **one God** who created us? . . .”
>
> 1 Corinthians 8:6  “there is actually to us **one God**, the Father,. . .
>
> Ephesians 4:6  “one God and Father . . .”
>
> 1 Timothy 2:5   “For there is **one God**, and one mediator between God and men,. . .”
>
> James 2:19  “You believe that there is **one God**, do you? . . .”

All the above texts refer to **“one God”** (The Father) who is called “Jehovah” in The Bible (Psalm 83:18 K.J.V.).   He alone is the *“Most High”* and Almighty God, “El shaddai” in Hebrew *(LXX Pantokrator (All Powerful))*;  this term is only applied to Jehovah in The Bible and no one else.  This would be the “one God” whom you ask about, the Creator and The “One” Almighty.

Comment: “Don’t we all have the same father? Didn’t one God create us all? Then why do we break faith with each other, profaning the covenant of our ancestors?”
‭‭Mal'akhi (Mal)‬ ‭2:10‬ ‭CJB‬‬
Same father is Abraham, same Creator and sustainer of all things is Jesus and not the Father. John 1:3, & 1:10, Colossians 1:16, 1 Corinthians 8:6, all these verses speak of Jesus being the Creator and Sustainer. The only way to bring the Father into the picture is if you apply echâd but considering Jesus calls Himself the alphaomega or the AlephTav or the et, it’s hard to get away from Genesis 1:1 being Jesus

Comment: @Mr Constantin  No we do not all have the same father, far from it according to The Bible we all have one of two!!  John made this very clear at: 1 John 3:10   "The children of God and the children of the Devil are evident by this fact: Whoever does not practice righteousness does not originate with God, nor does the one who does not love his brother."  It is one or the other.   This was the same in Eden and is the same today.

Comment: I’m sorry but that not how to exegete the texts unless you’re trying to fit it into a predetermined paradigm.

Comment: I keep trying but there is no way in Malachi 2 that you can get two fathers or that the one father it’s speaking of it the devil. I’m twisting it every which way to make it fit your interpretation and it’s just not working. The father he is talking about is their father in faith Abraham. The author is associating himself with those who have v11 married the daughter of a foreign god. By default they must both have two fathers according to your explanation but he speaks only of one and unless the author is says that his father is the devil too then why would his words be inspired by the Spirit?

Comment: @Mr Constantin  Try this; "One God" & "One Father" & "One Jehovah."  - Deuteronomy 6:4 "Listen, O Israel: Jehovah our God is one Jehovah. - Mark 12:29 "The first is, ‘Hear, O Israel, Jehovah our God is one Jehovah,"  Nothing else in The Cosmos is called Jehovah!  This is what The Boble says.

Comment: You realize that it’s not the English translation that is inspired but the original which was Hebrew and Greek right? That’s not what it says in Hebrew. It doesn’t say singular one or yachid, it says united one or echâd. If it were yachid you’d have a point but unfortunately you have phrases like, let US make man in OUR image. Or you have the Lord said to my Lord, or you have the Angel receiving worship and calling Himself divine, or you have Elohim which is the plural form of El (singular) sitting on multiple thrones reserved only for Divine Being. The concept of the trinity is OT not NT

Comment: @Mr Constantin  The Jews were Monotheistic not Triadic.   The New Encyclopædia Britannica: “The trinitarian creed of Christianity . . . sets it apart from the two other classical monotheistic religions [Judaism and Islām].” ... "the Bible of Christians includes no assertions about God that are specifically trinitarian.”

Comment: “But the angel of the Lord called to him from heaven and said, "Abraham, Abraham!" And he said, "Here I am." He said, "Do not lay your hand on the boy or do anything to him, for now I know that you fear God, seeing you have not withheld your son, your only son, from ME."”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭22:11-12‬ ‭ESV‬‬ the Angel positions Himself as God.

Comment: a man was standing before him with his drawn sword in his hand. And Joshua went to him and said to him, "Are you for us, or for our adversaries?" And he said, "No; but I am the commander of the army of the Lord. Now I have come." And Joshua fell on his face to the earth and worshiped and said to him, "What does my lord say to his servant?" And the commander of the Lord 's army said to Joshua, "Take off your sandals from your feet, for the place where you are standing is holy." And Joshua did so.”
‭‭Joshua‬ ‭5:13-15‬ ‭ESV‬‬ notice he accepted worship and called the ground Holy (like God would)

Comment: “This is the one who was in the congregation in the wilderness with the ANGEL who spoke to him at Mount Sinai, and with our fathers. He received living oracles to give to us.” ‭‭Acts‬ ‭7:38‬ ‭ESV‬‬ “The Lord spoke to Moses on Mount Sinai, saying,” ‭‭Leviticus‬ ‭25:1‬ ‭ESV‬‬ Again it’s the Angel that was speaking. There are plenty more OT examples, it’s just that the Pharisees suppressed this knowledge because they realized all these aligned with Jesus and gave credibility to Christianity.

Comment: @Mr Constantin  True That was Jesus on assignment from Jehovah as he Rep.

Comment: I like that idea except it has a major flaw. A representative is not allowed to receive worship. “Then Jesus said to him, "Be gone, Satan! For it is written, "'You shall worship the Lord your God and him only shall you serve.'"”
‭‭Mat‬ ‭4:10‬ ‭ESV‬‬ and notice also “And again, when he brings the firstborn into the world, he says, "Let all God's angels worship him." Of the angels he says, "He makes his angels winds, and his ministers a flame of fire." But of the Son he says, "Your throne, O God, is forever and ever, the scepter of uprightness is the scepter of your kingdom.”
‭‭Heb 1:6-8‬ ‭ESV

Comment: @Mr Constantin  You make some good points.  Ref. Heb 1:6-8  & the ref to Worship of Jesus is interesting but jesus pointed worship in another direction at:   John 4:23  "Nevertheless, the hour is coming, and it is now, when the true worshippers will worship the Father with spirit and truth, for indeed, the Father is looking for ones like these to worship him."  Directing Worship to the Father ,Jehovah!!??

Comment: Yeah, the Father says worship the Son and the Son says worship the Father. JWs have stopped coming to my house for some reason. “one God and Father of all who is over all and through all and in all.”
‭‭Ephesians‬ ‭4:6‬ ‭NASB‬‬
Here we have the Father all in all. “a renewal in which there is no distinction between Greek and Jew, circumcised and uncircumcised, barbarian, Scythian, slave and freeman, but Christ is all, and in all.”
‭‭Colossians‬ ‭3:11‬ ‭NASB‬‬
And now the Son is all and in all. If you read One and think singularity then it’s a contradiction if you read echâd that makes sense.

Comment: @MrConstantin  Interesting. As Jesus himself was a Jehovah's Witness - Said of Hebrews, Jesus was a Hebrew =  Isaiah 43:10-12 "“You are my witnesses,” declares Jehovah, “Yes, my servant whom I have chosen, So that you may know and have faith in me And understand that I am the same One. Before me no God was formed, And after me there has been none. 11 I—I am Jehovah, and besides me there is no savior.” 12 “I am the One who declared and saved and made known When there was no foreign god among you. So you are my witnesses,” declares Jehovah, “and I am God."  He would teach the  Worship of Jehovah

Comment: This whole passage is describing His servant and He calls him El. Consider the context and compare it with what happened in the life of Jesus. The alignment is very good. So it flies in the face of the argument that this is the Father that is being referenced. You just found another passage this time in the OT that confirms the deity of Jesus. Also the opening of the chapter starts with Elohim so it doesn’t deny the trinity it only emphasizes that in the verses you quoted only one El is being referenced and not all three and it happens to be the servant or Jesus. Thank you for sharing.